# Kotlin. Find element by param in nested lists

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have some `data clases`

```
data class Data(val docNumber: Int?,
            val docType: Int?, 
            val fiscprops: List<FiscProp>, 
            val name: String? 
 ) {

fun getFiscProp(tag: Int) = fiscprops.firstOrNull { it.tag == tag }

}

data class FiscProp(val caption: String?,
                val printable: String?,
                val tag: Int?,
                val value: Any?,
                val fiscprops: List<FiscProp>?)
```

I need to find `FiscProp` by `tag` in nested `lists`. If I use `getFiscProp` I can find `FiscProp` only if it is on first level of hierarchy.

How can I find element on the all levels? I don't know how many levels will be.

Comment: What do you mean by nested lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val FiscProp.allProps: Sequence<FiscProp>
    get() = sequence {
        yield(this@allProps)
        fiscprops?.forEach {
            yieldAll(it.allProps)
        }
    }

class Data(...) {

    fun getFiscProp(tag: Int) = fiscprops.asSequence()
        .flatMap { it.allProps}
        .firstOrNull { it.tag == tag }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a basic recursive search for this:

```
fun List<FiscProp>.getFiscProp(tag: Int): FiscProp? {
    for (fiscProp in this) {
        if (fiscProp.tag == tag)
            return fiscProp
        val found = fiscProp.fiscprops?.getFiscProp(tag)
        if (found != null)
            return found
    }
    return null
}
```

I think this functional version might work too, but I didn't test it:

```
fun List<FiscProp>.getFiscProp(tag: Int): FiscProp? = firstNotNullOfOrNull {
    if (it.tag == tag) it else it.fiscprops?.getFiscProp(tag)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your version requires the use of a companion object, but IR42's version doesn't. Which one is preferable and faster?

Comment: Why would mine require a companion? At first glance they both look the same in performance to me. I guess there are more allocations in the other answer but the advantage with that one is that the `allProps` property is versatile in case there are other types of searches you want to do.

Comment: By more allocations I just mean the Sequence objects, which are very lightweight.

Comment: How can I use this function as member Data class?

Comment: `fun getFiscProp(tag: String) = fiscProps.getFiscProp(tag)`

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tail-recursive version.

```
data class Data(...) {
    fun findByTag(tag: Int) = findByTag(fiscprops, tag)

    private tailrec fun findByTag(fiscprops: List<FiscProp>, tag: Int): FiscProp? =
        if (fiscprops.isEmpty()) null
        else {
            val fiscprop = fiscprops.first()
            if (fiscprop.tag == tag) fiscprop
            else findByTag(fiscprops.drop(1) + fiscprop.fiscprops.orEmpty(), tag)
        }
}
```